# Change / fix font on nav bar

Tags: html, css, navbar

Good morning! I recently download a template from this http://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page203/newsfeed. The nav bar display kind of weird font when I use Vietnamese letter on it. 
Sample: Nước it will show as all uppercase and letter uo will be shortened. I tried change transitions to capitalize but it still all uppercase.
I tried changed font but seems can't fix.

[this is picture how they look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnLMU.jpg)

HTML code

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/font.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/li-scroller.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/slick.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/jquery.fancybox.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/theme.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="assets/js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="preloader">
  <div id="status">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<a class="scrollToTop" href="#"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>
<div class="container">
  <header id="header">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="header_top">
      <div class="header_top_left">
        <ul class="top_nav">
          <li><a href="index.php">Nước  <-- trouble guy here</a></li>    
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="pages/contact.html">Liên Hệ</a></li>
```

style css:

```
#navArea{float:left; display:inline; width:100%; padding:0 30px; background-color:#fff}
.navbar{border:medium none; border-radius:0}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a{border-left:1px solid #383838; color:#ddd; font-family:'Oswald',sans-serif; display:inline-block; height:50px; line-height:50px; padding:0 14px; text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000; text-transform:capitalize; -webkit-transition:all 0.5s; -mz-transition:all 0.5s; -ms-transition:all 0.5s; -o-transition:all 0.5s; transition:all 0.5s}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li:first-child a{border:none}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus{ color:#fff}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > 
.active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus{ color:#fff}
.main-nav ul li a{}
.navbar-collapse{ padding-left:0}
.mobile-show{display:none}
.desktop-home{display:block; font-size:30px; margin-top:10px}
.dropdown-menu{background-color:#222}
.dropdown-menu > li > a{clear:both; color:#ddd; background-color:#222; padding:10px 20px; font-family:'Oswald',sans-serif; -webkit-transition:all 0.5s; -mz-transition:all 0.5s; -ms-transition:all 0.5s; -o-transition:all 0.5s; transition:all 0.5s}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus{color:#fff}
```

Any help ?

I'm really appreciate

Justin

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: I suppose the first thing to check would be; if the browser supports the language and if you have proper charset settings applied.

Comment: If you share the html and css, it'd be more helpful.  If you are changing the  text in the html, but it is staying uppercase, there is probably a "text-transform: uppercase" in the css.

Comment: Thanks Andy B, I came to style.css to change the transfrom: capitalized but still not change. I will up date the css at my lunch time 

Comment: here is my code

Comment: I have felling that the css stretch the letter up. If that so, please tell me how to bring the font back to normal size?

Answer (score 0):

after several attempts I found out that deleting the font.css line will fix the uneven scale letter when other language is used.